# Ocaml loop function

Tags: ocaml

I need to make a function that takes as inputs a function f and input b and calls f on b to return (b',c') b' is some result and c' is a boolean.  The function needs to then keep calling f on b' as long as c' is true

This is what I wrote:

```
let rec wwhile (f,b) = match f b with
| (a,c) -> if c then wwhile(f a,c) else a
;;
```

the idea is I want to get the tuple result of f b and check if c is true but im not sure it using pattern matching is the best way to accomplish this.  Also this function gives me a syntax error which im not sure why

heres a sample correct asnwer:

```
# let f x = let xx = x*x*x in (xx,xx<100);;
val f : int -> int * bool = fn
# wwhile (f,2);;
- : int = 512
```

figured out correct code:

```
let rec wwhile (f,b) = match f b with
| (a,c) -> if c then wwhile(f ,a) else a
;;
```

Comment: Ocaml has call by value semantics. Perhaps you should consider making the condition argument a function giving a boolean, not a boolean value.

Comment: yeah i just realized that before i saw this im retarded lol

Comment: you should define the function like `let rec wwhile f b` instead of the tuple pattern match `wwhile (f,b)`.